# Electron BrowserWindow shows taskbar when focused

Tags: focus, electron, taskbar, always-on-top

My application is an overlay (alwaysOnTop) for a full screen game and when the user clicks on my overlay it takes focus and shows the taskbar on top of their game as well. Taking focus is fine, but I can't have the taskbar show.

It says in the [BrowserWindow docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetalwaysontopflag):

> not a toolbox window which can not be focused on

Implying that it is possible to create a window which cannot be focused on.

Does anyone know how to create a toolbox window, or to simply avoid having the taskbar showing when clicking on the electron window?

---

I should mention I've tried `setAlwaysOnTop` and `skipTaskbar`. I also have `transparent: true` and `frame: false`.

---

The overlay I've created is the "Safelane, Midlane, Offlane" buttons. When I run the application it shows on top of the full screen app (Dota 2) like this:

[image]

After clicking on the interface the taskbar appears. It would be fine that the full screen app (Dota) loses focus, the task bar appears on top which breaks the continuity of the experience:

[image]

I would like the experience to stay like the first image--when the user clicks on anything in my overlay, the taskbar should not show.

[Electron GitHub Issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5994)

---

**Additional Solution Info** -- After using Gaafar's solution below

Setting `kiosk: true` in the setup does not seem to allow it to render transparent. Using `setKiosk(true)` within a `setTimeout` after the window has been opened seemed to work.

I also found that any windows using `kiosk` or `fullscreen` with transparency had rendering issue. It would render multiple times on top of itself and could not unrender items (display: none in css would do nothing). The way I fixed this was by using [Electron Window Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-window-manager) creating a single `kiosk` window with nothing in it and creating other non-kiosk windows with the HTML / CSS interfaces. The result:

1. All of the interfaces can be interacted with, mouse and keyboard.
2. Rendering happens as it does regularly in electron.
3. The fullscreen application below receives input through any transparent areas.
4. Taskbar never shows up on any input.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of what is happening and what you want to happen?

Comment: Done. Let me know if I can add anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`skipTaskbar: true` is to prevent showing your app in the taskbar.

To hide the taskbar altogether use fullscreen or kiosk mode instead

`fullscreen: true`
or
`kiosk: true`

EDIT: 
There are some issues open where fullscreen or kiosk modes prevent the transparency of the window. 
A solution that works for me is to run with these flags `--enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu`

issue & solution: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2170#issuecomment-145942717

Comment: I was worried that fullscreen mode would prevent clicks in transparent areas, but it looks like it's going to work! 

I'll see if I can fully implement it and if all is well I'll accept and award, thank you very much!

Comment: sure, let me know if you face other issues

Comment: The only issue I ran into is that I can't set `kiosk: true` in the setup or immediately after opening the window. I have `setTimeout` long enough to have it render first, then doing `setKiosk(true);` works, otherwise the window would not stay render transparent.

Answer (score 0):

1. showInActive();
2. set your BrowserWindows, focusable: false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna post a solution some might be facing with full screening, I was facing this issue and wandering here and there, this StackOverflow post kept coming up.

So Im posting it here so people getting similar problems can get help.

> When fullscreening taskbar getting in way.

When you fullscreen using mainWindow.setFullScreen(true) taskbar will get in way when you are on home (all windows minimized) in windows.

Here is the solution:

```
ipcMain.on("fullscreenon",()=>{
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen-saver');
  mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
})
//The order of the commands is important below
//don't setAlwaysOnTop() before getting out of fullscreen.
ipcMain.on("fullscreenoff",()=>{
  mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'floating')
})
```

Basically, by default setFullscreen uses the level: "floating". We need a higher level, "screen-saver" is the highest level I think.